# Grant a user permission on a document using Share or using the Advance permission settings

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, administration, share

We have a document library inside a communication online site, and we have 2 approaches to share a file with a user who do not have access to the site:-

1. Select the Document >> Using the Share link:-
   [image]
2. Select the Document >> click on "Manage Access" >> click on "Advance" >> stop the permission inheritance >> grant the user access to the file:-
   [image]

in both cases the user will have access to the file, but is there any differences between the above 2 approaches? or they will satisfy the same need?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint, there are typically multiple ways to do the same thing. The quick answer is that yes, these two options are similar and can be used interchangeably.

However, there are some subtle differences. For example, by using the **first approach**, you have access to the "Share a link feature". You can also set the expiration of the link and other settings.

The **advanced** approach does not have the "share a link" feature, but gives you an ability to share a document with a SharePoint Group. On top of that, using the "advanced" approach, you have more control over how a document is shared and with who exactly.

Answer (score 1):

They can both share files with users, but there are some differences in some functions.

1.Select the Document -> Using the Share link.

This share function can be controlled in the SharePoint Online admin center. This function is mostly used to share files with external users. You can also set the expiration of the link and other settings.

Reference:

[Manage sharing settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off)

[External sharing overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/external-sharing-overview)

2.Select the Document -> Click on "Manage Access" -> Click on "Advance" -> Stop the permission inheritance -> Grant the user access to the file.

You can share files with multiple uses and groups.